# Is there a way to covert Unicode Hex Character Code &#x61; to a simple "a" so that I can get an alphabetic string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, unicode-string

This character format encoding description can be found in [All such encoded characters](https://www.howtocreate.co.uk/sidehtmlentity.html) and [character description](https://www.codetable.net/hex/61). The exact specific string I want to convert is-

> -9<ahref="j&#x61vascript:&#x61lert(window.origin)">X

This should be converted to-

> -9<ahref="javascript:alert(window.origin)">X

I am a beginner in C# and have very little knowledge of this encoding style. Please help. I want something like Encoding.{what-is-the-format}.GetString(encodedString) => returns decodedString.

Comment: Look at the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode method to decode those html entities. Be aware in your example semicolons are missing. Such encoded characters always end in a semicolon.

Comment: Thank you @Ralf but using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode method gives no difference in the output so I belive it isn't working. Here is a sample output: `HTML Encoded string is: -9&lt;ahref=\&quot;j&amp;#x61;vascript:&amp;#x61;lert(window.origin)\&quot;&gt;X
Decoded string of the above encoded string is: -9<ahref=\"j&#x61;vascript:&#x61;lert(window.origin)\">X`

Comment: Your encoded string looks like as if has been encoded twice and it contains backslashes as if used in an escaped literal. That will not work. HtmlUtility.HtmlDecode will work if you use valid html encoded input. You now used invalid input the second time. Programming isn't magic. If you throw in garbage you get garbage out simple a that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, thanks to [@Ralf's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057662/is-there-a-way-to-covert-unicode-hex-character-code-x61-to-a-simple-a-so-th/72494485#comment127344686_72057662):

- Step 1: Used Regex to extract unicode-hex character format from my
  string
- Step 2: Used `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` to decode the extracted matches
- Step 3: Replaced the decoded characters in my original string

Complete C# code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class MyNewClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {            
            var textWithCountryNames= "-9<ahref=\"j&#x61;vascript:&#x61;lert(window.origin)\">X";
           
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(textWithCountryNames, @"&#x?[^;]{2}\;?", 
            delegate(Match match)
            {
                string v= match.ToString();
                return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(v.EndsWith(";")? v : v+";");
            }
            , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
                 
    }
}
```